# How do you view custom fields from ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have created an IdentityUser within my Identity Model:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{

    // *** Custom field variables for users ***

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public DateTime AccountOpen { get; set; }

    // *** Custom field variables for users ***

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    // *** Modify table and primary key names ***
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserClaimID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("RoleID");
    }
    // *** Modify table and primary key names ***

}
```

I have created a simple UserController to allow me to simply view all users on the database.  I intend to use this to administer the site.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using acme.Models;

namespace acme.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Users
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var users = context.Users.ToList();
            return View(users);
        }

    }
}
```

Finally, I have created the view page:

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    <p><strong>@user.UserName</strong></p>
    <p>@user.FirstName</p>
}
```

Although the @user.UserName works fine, the @user.FirstName is not working at all and generating an error 'IdentityUser' does not contain a definition...

I have checked through and the database looks good (as I have defined the user in the RegisterViewModel).  I just can't seem to figure out why the custom field is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have worked it out.  I don't need:

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>
```

because I am already passing the list into the view.  Once I removed it, it all worked just fine.

Benefits of a good night sleep.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are using the default IdentityUser, not your own,

change

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>
```

to:

```
@model IEnumerable<namespace.to.my.User>
```

Comment: Felipe: Thank you for your advice. I tried what you had suggested and was receiving the same issue.  However, as I was passing the data as a list in the UserController, once I removed the @Model line, it worked a treat!